# Is there a term for a blood pressure level that is too high but which is typical for the patient and causes no symptoms?

Tags: terminology, blood-pressure

In Russian, there is a semi-colloquial medical term "рабочее давление" (working pressure) - the blood pressure that is excessive, but is typical for this particular patient and causes no symptoms in him/her.

For instance, a person may have a blood pressure of 140/90 chronically yet feel nothing out of the ordinary. In the past, doctors would say "it's just your working pressure, if you feel okay, your organism must have adapted". Today this is considered unscientific and is actively discouraged, but the colloquial term remains.

Problematically, the term tends to crop up in documents that a translator like me has to translate into English, so the translator has to come up with some English term.

I wonder if there is a term in English for this.

Comment: With regard to what is high blood and what is normal blood pressure, [this article](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/324697#Moving-away-from-a-blanket-approach) talks of some interesting research findings.

Comment: I don't think a comparable term exists, but proving a negative is almost impossible so I don't know how the question can be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a historical and obsolete term in English called [Benign hypertension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benign_hypertension). According to the [History of hypertension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_hypertension) article in Wikipedia:

> ... hypertension was often classified into "malignant" and "benign" ... Charles Friedberg's 1949 classic textbook "Diseases of the Heart",[17] stated that "people with 'mild benign' hypertension ... [defined as blood pressures up to levels of 210/100 mm Hg] ... need not be treated".[15] However, the tide of medical opinion was turning: it was increasingly recognised in the 1950s that **"benign" hypertension was not harmless**.[18] Over the next decade increasing evidence accumulated from actuarial reports[2][19] and longitudinal studies, such as the Framingham Heart Study,[20] that "benign" hypertension increased death and cardiovascular disease.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this expression: **habitual blood pressure**. I don't know how common it is.

An excerpt from *[Constitutional disorders of homeostasis. The genetic aspect of diabetes mellitus, essential hypertension and obesity](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/amg-acta-geneticae-medicae-et-gemellologiae-twin-research/article/constitutional-disorders-of-homeostasis-the-genetic-aspect-of-diabetes-mellitus-essential-hypertension-and-obesity/F191D93B196EB0E00B234A0AC851DEB7)* by Julius Bauer:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer for your original question. I would take "habitual" in this case to just mean "typical for a given person". You would also call a blood pressure that isn't too high a "habitual" pressure.